# VB.NET - Timer not working properly with thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, timer

I'm developing a small app that sends data to a microcontroller. Anyway, a part of it contains downloading data from a web server once in a second and forward that data to the microcontroller if the data has changed. To repeat the procedure once a second, I'm calling a timer. To fetch data from the internet, I'm using a thread. The problem is, the timer stops repeating itself in regular intervals after a certain (random, but usually 1-3) number of executions. May be, it waits for the thread to fetch data from the internet, but I'm not sure as it keeps stuck there forever. The code's below.

Timer Code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf dlstatus)
    thread.Start()

 If ((s1sub1 <> s2sub1)) Then

            'Func1

        ElseIf (s2sub2 = "n") Then

            'Func2
Endif


End sub
```

dlstatus function which is called using a thread

```
Private Sub dlstatus()
        str2 = enc.GetString(wc.DownloadData(link2))
End sub
```

I want the timer to keep on looping without stopping. Any idea how to make it so? Please help. Thanks..

P.S Please let me know if you need any more details...

Comment: Surely you could just use a `While...End` statement? Forgive me if I'm oversimplifying greatly..

Comment: Put that `While...End` loop in a **BackgroundWorker()** DoWork() handler and make it Sleep() for one second at the bottom so it refreshes again one second after the last update was completed.  Just use that one thread provided by the BackgroundWorker(); no need for any more.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your reply. BackgroundWorker is doing the job fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve, you want to discard the timer and use a `while` loop.  Setting a timer to run every second to run a process that has an unknown execution time is likely run into problems very quickly.  Using a `while` loop will simply allow the code to complete and loop when it is ready meaning it could be less than a second or more than a minute if the response was that slow.

Answer (score 0):

When I create Timer.Tick events, I normally stop and restart the Timer as the first and last call in that function.

Otherwise if your code takes longer thyan a second to run, it risks tripping over the heals of the last call that you made.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Stop ' pause the timer until this call has finished

    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf dlstatus)
    thread.Start()

    If ((s1sub1 <> s2sub1)) Then
         'Func1
    ElseIf (s2sub2 = "n") Then
         'Func2
    Endif

    Timer1.Start ' we've finished the call, restart the timer  
End sub
```

However, you may also find that a background worker thread is a better option:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx